# Many to many join Php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

I have two tables "Personne" and "email". One person can have several emails, and one email can be associated with several people:

```
    Personne
+-------------+--------------+
| idPers      | int(10)      |
| ...         | ...          |
+-------------+--------------+
    email
+-------------+--------------+
| idEmail     | int(10)      |
| ...         | ...          |
+-------------+--------------+
```

I then created a bridge between the two:

```
 pers_email
+-------------+--------------+
| id          | int(10)      |
| idPers      | int(10)      |
| idEmail     | int(10)      |
+-------------+--------------+
```

I want to get all the emails associated with one person, I've been using this piece of code:

```
$q='SELECT *
from AERA.pers_email , AERA.email
join AERA.email e on e.idEmail = pers_mail.idEmail
where pers_email.idPers = '.$idPers;

$query = $linkpdo->prepare($q);
$query->execute();
$email = $query->fetchAll();
```

but I can't get it working, it keeps throwing various yet vague errors such as:

> 1054 Unknown column 'pers_mail.idEmail' in 'on clause''

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have `pers_mail.idEmail`, you should have `pers_email.idEmail` and you should only inner join once, what you have will do a cross join and then join again which might produced unwanted results. try this

```
$q='SELECT *
from AERA.pers_email 
inner join AERA.email e on e.idEmail = pers_email.idEmail
where pers_email.idPers = '.$idPers;
```

also just appending $idPers to the sql might expose you to sql injections.